# How can I allow the user to view his available account balances for two different currencies & Write transactions to file either deposit or withdrawal

Tags: java, user-interface, project

This application should mimic the basic functions of an ATM machine. You should create a typical ATM user interface as well as create files from which you can read your saved transactions or write to it your new daily transactions. Your GUI should look like a real ATM machine and be able to perform the following functions:

1. Log the user using (password protected text field).
2. Allow the user to make withdrawals (don't allow them to overdraw).
3. Allow the user to make deposits.
4. Write transactions to file i.e. either deposit or withdrawal.
5. Read from file and print the transactions for a given account between two given dates.
6. Allow the user to view his available account balances i.e. for two different currencies.
7. Print a receipt for either a deposit or a withdrawal.
8. Read from file and print all clients that their balances are above 10000$.

1st class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Login extends JFrame {

    String pin = "1234";
    int attempts = 3;
    public Login(){
        //Basic Constructor Setup
        super("Login Screen");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        buildApp();
        pack();
        setSize(250, 110);
        setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Login();        
    }
    
    void buildApp(){
        //===================================================
        //GUI Setup
        //===================================================       
        JLabel pinInstruction = new JLabel("Please enter your pin number");
        JPasswordField pinText = new JPasswordField(4);
        JButton entPin = new JButton("Enter");
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        buttonPanel.add(quit);
        buttonPanel.add(entPin);
        pinText.setBackground(Color.white);
        add(pinInstruction, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(pinText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        //===================================================
        //Action Listener Setup
        //===================================================
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }   
        });
        
        pinText.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                char[] pinGuess = pinText.getPassword();
                String pinString = new String(pinGuess);
                if(pinString.equals(pin)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That pin is correct! Opening Account...");
                    dispose();
                    new ATM();
                } else{
                    if(attempts != 1){
                        attempts--;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That pin is incorrect! \n" + attempts 
                        + " attempts remaining!");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Attempts remaining! \n Closing Program");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }   
        });
        entPin.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                char[] pinGuess = pinText.getPassword();
                String pinString = new String(pinGuess);
                if(pinString.equals(pin)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That pin is correct! Opening Account...");
                    dispose();
                    new ATM();
                } else{
                    if(attempts != 1){
                        attempts--;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That pin is incorrect! \n" + attempts 
                        + " attempts remaining!");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Attempts remaining! \n Closing Program");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

2nd class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ATM extends JFrame {
    //Variables for balance, the input from the user for deposits,
    //and for checking that they have clicked Deposit before clicking Enter
    int balance = 10;
    String[] inputSequence = new String[4];
    String[] transactionHist = new String[100];
    int inputSequenceIndex = 0;
    int transactionIndex = 0;
    boolean readyToEnter = false;
    //Basic Constructor Setup - Setting the input array as empty
    //Other basic setup options - Setting size, locaion etc, building app
    public ATM(){
        super("ATM");
        for(int i =0; i <= 3; i++){
            inputSequence[i] = "";
        }
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        buildApp();
        pack();
        setSize(600, 350);
        setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    protected void buildApp(){
        //==================================
        //GUI Setup (VIEW)
        //==================================
        //Basic Panel layout setup
        JLabel displayArea = new JLabel("<html>Instruction Area: <br> Please select a function from the buttons below <br> Current Balance: \u00A3" + balance + "</html>");
        displayArea.setOpaque(true);
        displayArea.setBackground(Color.white);
        displayArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        JPanel bottomArea = new JPanel();
        bottomArea.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
        JLabel inputDisplay = new JLabel("Input Area:");
        inputDisplay.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        bottomArea.add(inputDisplay, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        //Grid layout setup for buttons
        GridBagLayout buttonGrid = new GridBagLayout();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(buttonGrid);
        GridBagConstraints bPConst = new GridBagConstraints();
    
        //Buttons SETUP
        bPConst.weightx= 0.1;
        bPConst.weighty= 0.1;
        JButton withDraw1 = new JButton("Withdraw \u00A35");
        bPConst.gridx = 0;
        bPConst.gridy = 0;  
        bPConst.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        withDraw1.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(withDraw1, bPConst);
        JButton withDraw2 = new JButton("Withdraw \u00A310");
        bPConst.gridx = 0;
        bPConst.gridy = 1;
        withDraw2.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(withDraw2, bPConst);
        JButton withDraw3 = new JButton("Withdraw \u00A320");
        bPConst.gridx = 0;
        bPConst.gridy = 2;
        withDraw3.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(withDraw3, bPConst);
        JButton deposit = new JButton("Deposit");
        bPConst.gridx = 0;
        bPConst.gridy = 3;
        deposit.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(deposit, bPConst);
        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        bPConst.gridx = 0;
        bPConst.gridy = 4;
        bPConst.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        quit.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(quit, bPConst);
        JButton number1 = new JButton("1");
        bPConst.gridx = 1;
        bPConst.gridy = 0;
        number1.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number1, bPConst);
        JButton number2 = new JButton("2");
        bPConst.gridx = 2;
        bPConst.gridy = 0;
        number2.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number2, bPConst);
        JButton number3 = new JButton("3");
        bPConst.gridx = 3;
        bPConst.gridy = 0;
        number3.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number3, bPConst);
        JButton number4 = new JButton("4");
        bPConst.gridx = 1;
        bPConst.gridy = 1;
        number4.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number4, bPConst);
        JButton number5 = new JButton("5");
        bPConst.gridx = 2;
        bPConst.gridy = 1;
        number5.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number5, bPConst);
        JButton number6 = new JButton("6");
        bPConst.gridx = 3;
        bPConst.gridy = 1;
        number6.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number6, bPConst);
        JButton number7 = new JButton("7");
        bPConst.gridx = 1;
        bPConst.gridy = 2;
        number7.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number7, bPConst);
        JButton number8 = new JButton("8");
        bPConst.gridx = 2;
        bPConst.gridy = 2;
        number8.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number8, bPConst);
        JButton number9 = new JButton("9");
        bPConst.gridx = 3;
        bPConst.gridy = 2;
        number9.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number9, bPConst);
        JButton number0 = new JButton("0");
        bPConst.gridx = 1;
        bPConst.gridy = 3;
        number0.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(number0, bPConst);
        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
        bPConst.gridx = 2;
        bPConst.gridy = 3;
        clear.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        buttonPanel.add(clear, bPConst);
        JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
        bPConst.gridx = 3;
        bPConst.gridy = 3;
        enter.setSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        //Adding everything to the layouts above
        buttonPanel.add(enter, bPConst);
        bottomArea.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(displayArea,  BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(bottomArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        //==================================
        //Action Listener Setup (CONTROLLER)
        //==================================
        // 3 Withdraw buttons (Simply minus from balance if balance is not below amount):
        withDraw1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if(balance >= 5){
                    balance = balance - 5;
                    displayArea.setText("<html>\u00A35 Withrawn! <br><br>" + finishedTransaction() + "</html>");
                    readyToEnter = false;
                    System.out.println("User Has Withdrawn \u00A35");
                    updateTransactionHist("User Has Withdrawn \u00A35");
                } else {
                    displayArea.setText("<html> Your Balance is below \u00A35. Unable to Withdraw!! <br><br>" 
                    + finishedTransaction() + "</html>");
                }
            }   
        });
        withDraw2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if(balance >= 10){
                    balance = balance - 10;
                    displayArea.setText("<html>\u00A310 Withrawn! <br><br>" + finishedTransaction() + "</html>");
                    readyToEnter = false;
                    System.out.println("User Has Withdrawn \u00A310");
                    updateTransactionHist("User Has Withdrawn \u00A310");
                } else {
                    displayArea.setText("<html> Your Balance is below \u00A310. Unable to Withdraw!! <br><br>" 
                    + finishedTransaction() + "</html>");
                }
                
            }   
        });
        withDraw3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if(balance >= 20){
                    balance = balance - 20;
                    displayArea.setText("<html>\u00A320 Withrawn! <br><br>" + finishedTransaction() + "</html>");
                    readyToEnter = false;
                    System.out.println("User Has Withdrawn \u00A320");
                    updateTransactionHist("User Has Withdrawn \u00A320");
                } else {
                    displayArea.setText("<html> Your Balance is below \u00A320. Unable to Withdraw!! <br><br>" 
                    + finishedTransaction() + "</html>");
                }
            }   
        });
        // Quit Button - Return to login
        quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Receipt: \n" + printReceipt());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logging Out! Returning to Login Screen!");
                dispose();
                new Login();
            }   
        });
        // Clear Button - Clear the input array (Method at bottom)
        clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: ");
                displayArea.setText("<html>Input Area Cleared! <br><br>" 
                + finishedTransaction() +"</html>");
                clearInput();
                readyToEnter = false;
            }   
        });
        // Number Buttons - Add a number to the input array
        number1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("1"));
            }   
        });
        number2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("2"));
            }   
        });
        number3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("3"));
            }   
        });
        number4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("4"));
            }   
        });
        number5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("5"));
            }   
        });
        number6.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("6"));
            }   
        });
        number7.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("7"));
            }   
        });
        number8.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("8"));
            }   
        });
        number9.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("9"));
            }   
        });
        number0.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: " + updateInput("0"));
            }   
        });
        // Deposit Button - Primes program for a deposit, allows user to click enter deposit
        deposit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    displayArea.setText("<html> Deposit Selected! <br> Please input an amout below or equal to \u00A31000 and click enter! <br><br>" 
                    + finishedTransaction() + "</html>" );
                    readyToEnter = true;
            }   
        });
        // Enter Button - adds input array val to balance
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if(readyToEnter == true){
                    if(Integer.parseInt(getInputSequence()) > 1000){
                        displayArea.setText("That input is greater than \u00A31000!");
                        clearInput();
                        inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: ");
                        readyToEnter = false;
                    } else if(Integer.parseInt(getInputSequence()) == 0 || getInputSequence().equals("0000")){
                        displayArea.setText("You have not entered a value!");
                        clearInput();
                        inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: ");
                        readyToEnter = false;
                    } else {
                        updateBalance(Integer.parseInt(getInputSequence()));
                        displayArea.setText("<html> You have deposited \u00A3" + getInputSequence() 
                        + "! <br><br>" + finishedTransaction() + "</html>");
                        System.out.println("User Has Deposited \u00A3" + getInputSequence());
                        updateTransactionHist("User Has Deposited \u00A3" + getInputSequence());
                    }
                    clearInput();
                    inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: ");
                    readyToEnter = false;
                } else {
                    displayArea.setText("<html> You have not yet chosen an action! <br><br>" + finishedTransaction() + "</html>");
                    clearInput();
                    inputDisplay.setText("Input Display: ");
                }
                
            }   
        }); 
    } 
    //==================================
    //Extra Methods for calculations(MODEL)
    //==================================        
    //Clears the string and resets the Input area
    void clearInput(){
        for(int i =0; i <= 3; i++){
            inputSequence[i] = "";  
        }
        inputSequenceIndex = 0;
    }
    //Updates the Input area and the string with a new number when button clicked
    String updateInput(String n){
        if(inputSequenceIndex <= 3){
            inputSequence[inputSequenceIndex] = n;
            inputSequenceIndex++;
        
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < inputSequence.length; i++) {
                strBuilder.append(inputSequence[i]);
            }
            String newString = strBuilder.toString();
            return newString;
        } else{
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                strBuilder.append(inputSequence[i]);
            }
            String newString = strBuilder.toString();
            return newString;
        }
    }
    
    String getInputSequence(){
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if(inputSequence[0] == ""){
            return "0000";
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputSequence.length; i++) {
                strBuilder.append(inputSequence[i]);
            }
            String newString = strBuilder.toString();
            return newString;
        }
    }
    //Resetting the label to its original state with new balance
    String finishedTransaction(){
        return "Instruction Area: <br> Please select a function from the buttons below <br> Current Balance: \u00A3" + balance;
    }
    //Updating balance upon deposit
    void updateBalance(int l){
        balance += l;
    }
    //Updating the transaction history for the final receipt
    void updateTransactionHist(String t){
        transactionHist[transactionIndex] = t;
        transactionIndex++;
    }
    //Put the final receipt together and return it for printing
    String printReceipt(){
        if(inputSequence[0].equals(null)){
            return "No Transactions Made!";
        } else{
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < transactionIndex; i++) {
                strBuilder.append(transactionHist[i] + "\n");
            }
            String newString = strBuilder.toString();
            return newString;
       }
    }
    //Main Method
    public static void main (String[] args){
        new Login();    
    }
    
}
```

[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQlJ3.png)

Comment: If you want clarification regarding the assignment, I think you need to ask the person who gave you the assignment. I'm guessing that you need to store the transaction details in a [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) where each line of the file contains details of a single transaction. Again guessing from the assignment, transaction details would include date, type (i.e. deposit or withdrawal), amount and account balance after the transaction.

Comment: This is an interesting assignment.  The [model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern will help you complete the assignment in a more structured manner.  First, you need to create an application model using plain Java getter/setter classes.  You need Account and Transaction classes, at a minimum.  You need to decide how you want to read and write the account and transaction information to a file or database.  You need to figure all this out before you write one line of Java Swing code.